# I am required to create an function identical to LISTAGG function in db2 but the seperator should be default to ','

Tags: sql, database, function, db2

The output of the **LISTAGG** is a string where the records of a specific column is seperated by a specified seperator. for an example,

`SELECT LISTAGG(COL1,',') FROM TABLE1`

gives the output in the form  ***record1,record2,record3,record4,record1,record3,record4***

and you can also specify the distict clause inside the LISTAGG function to filter out the repeating records for an example,

`SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT COL1,',') FROM TABLE1`

gives the output in the form  ***record1,record2,record3,record4***

=================================

As of the application using a function called **stringagg**, i am required to create a function with the similar name but also can be used to the extenct that using the function with a distinct clause is possible and the seperator is always **','**

the function should work this way,

`SELECT STRINGAGG(DISTINCT COL1) FROM TABLE1`

gives the output in the form  ***record1,record2,record3,record4***

I tried creating a function using a user defined aggregate function, It is successful but I cannot use distinct caluse inside. This is my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE erp.strag_initialize(OUT strag VARCHAR(4000))
LANGUAGE SQL 
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
               SET strag = '';

END
@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE erp.strag_accumulate(IN record VARCHAR(4000),  INOUT strag VARCHAR(4000))
LANGUAGE SQL 
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
               SET strag = concat(concat(strag,record), ',');
END
@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE erp.strag_merge(IN strag VARCHAR(4000), INOUT mergestr VARCHAR(4000))
LANGUAGE SQL 
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
               SET mergestr = concat(mergestr ,strag);
END
@

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION erp.strag_fin(strag VARCHAR(4000))
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
BEGIN
               RETURN strag;
END
@

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION erp.stragg(VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AGGREGATE WITH (strag VARCHAR(4000))
USING
INITIALIZE PROCEDURE erp.strag_initialize
ACCUMULATE PROCEDURE erp.strag_accumulate
MERGE PROCEDURE erp.strag_merge
FINALIZE FUNCTION erp.strag_fin
@
```

I also created a function using the listagg as a source function but it do not use **','** as the default seperator

Comment: Why are you re-writing listagg? Just to "fix" the separator to only a comma? seems very unnecessary

Comment: I agree with you, but changing the application code is much more time-consuming and could introduce more issues.

Comment: But how and from where is the new function called? Aren't there changes necessary?

Comment: The application team is required to run `SELECT STRINGAGG(DISTINCT COL1) FROM TABLE1 ` like queries from the database.

Comment: You are attempting to retain sql code on a new platform, without refactoring for that platform. Really? Unlikely that you won't need to change that code. Might as well use listagg IMHO.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am not in the position to that I am given only this task. Anyways I was able to do that. I will put that in answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this task by creating a function using the following syntax

```
create or replace function stringagg(varchar(4000),seperator varchar(4000) default ',')
returns varchar(4000)
source listagg(varchar(4000),varchar(4000))
```